# Kendo UI and Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, kendo-ui

My problem is relatively simple, but I have been trying for the last couple of hours to come up with a solution. http://chris1904.webege.com/#map you can see that first a map of Australia loads and after that it switches to loading an American map. I use the normal center function out of the Google Maps API V3

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.650052);
```

and this location loads after loading an Australian location. I would really appreciate any hints and tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is related with `mapMarker.js` during the initialization it creates a new google map and centers the position. If you pay attention to the code:

```
function initializeMap(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapProp = {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:5,
        //disableDefaultUI:true,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapProp);

    setMarkers(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);  
    });
}
```

You can see that it invokes `google.maps.Map` and places it in the HTML element `map_canvas` removing your mobile application layout but it also defines `center` as `myCenter` that is in USA.

You should review how you initialize it. My recommendation is replacing your `mapMarker.js` by:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'house.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32,37),    // size of the image
    new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin, in this case top-left corner
    new google.maps.Point(16, 18)    // anchor, i.e. the point half-way along the bottom of the image
);

function setMarkers(map) {
    // Add markers to the map
    // address, lat und lng lokal speichern und abrufen, so dass leads nicht verloren gehen
    latArr = $.jStorage.get("latKey");
    lngArr = $.jStorage.get("lngKey");
    compAddressArr = $.jStorage.get("addressKey");
    // beim ersten Test gibt es die Arrays noch nicht, deshalb einen Wert geben
    if (latArr == null && lngArr == null && compAddressArr == null) {
        latArr = ["workaround"];
        lngArr = ["workaround"];
        compAddressArr = ["workaround"];
    }
    else {
        // wenn die Variablen schon gefuellt sind und mehr als einen Eintrag haben, weil der erste ein workaround ist, dann einen marker auf die map zeichnen
        var amount2 = latArr.length;
        console.log(amount2);
        console.log(lngArr);
        console.log(latArr);
        console.log(compAddressArr);
        if (amount2 > 1) {
            for (var i = 1; i < amount2; i++ ) {
                // marker/lead zeichnen
                var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latArr[i], lngArr[i]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: compAddressArr[i],
                });
                var infowindowString = '<div id="content">'+
                    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Chris Breuer</h1>'+
                    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                    '<p><b>Phone Number</b>: (808)218-8241 <br>' +
                    '<p><b>Notes</b>:  Uluru, also referred to as Ayers Rock, is a large sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the Northern Territory, central Australia. Some random customer info here</p> '+
                    '<p><b>Address: </b>'+compAddressArr[i]+
                    '</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: infowindowString
                });
                // so dass man das Fenster oefters oeffnen kann
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}


function placeMarker(map, location) {
    var lat = location.lat();
    var lng = location.lng();

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    // This is making the Geocode request
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            alert(status);
        }
        // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
            var addressArr = address.split(",");
            console.log(addressArr);
            var street = addressArr[0].trim();
            var city = addressArr[1].trim();
            var zipState = addressArr[2].trim();
            var state = zipState.trim().substr(0,2);
            var zip = zipState.trim().substr(3,8);
            var country = addressArr[3] ? addressArr[3].trim() : "N/A";
            var completeAddress = street+" "+city+" "+state+" "+zip+" "+country;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: completeAddress,
            });

            var infowindowString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                '</div>'+
                '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Chris Breuer</h1>'+
                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                '<p><b>Phone Number</b>: (808)218-8241 <br>' +
                '<p><b>Notes</b>:  Uluru, also referred to as Ayers Rock, is a large sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the Northern Territory, central Australia. Some random customer info here</p> '+
                '<p><b>Address</b>'+completeAddress+
                '</p>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>';

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: infowindowString
            });
            // so dass man das Fenster oefters oeffnen kann
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });
            // address, lat und lng sind gleiche Anzahl, deshalb nur eine amount
            // localStorage nutzen und in Array speichern
            var amount = latArr.length;
            compAddressArr[amount] = completeAddress;
            latArr[amount] = lat;
            lngArr[amount] = lng;
            console.log(latArr);
            console.log(lngArr);
            console.log(compAddressArr);
            $.jStorage.set("latKey", latArr);
            $.jStorage.set("lngKey", lngArr);
            $.jStorage.set("addressKey", compAddressArr);
        }
    });
}
```

and `buildMap` function as:

```
//initialize the google map
function buildMap(e) {
    var myOptions = {
        center   : new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom     : 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var mapElement = $("#map_canvas");
    var container = e.view.content;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement[0], myOptions);

    setMarkers(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        placeMarker(map, event.latLng);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response. That was the answer I needed. It works on my localost without any problems now, but once I upload it to this webspace http://chris1904.bplaced.net/index.html#map I get the error message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL on this line google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {